# Twilio Request Validation always fail for Voice Call (but works for SMS)

Tags: c#, twilio, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi, twilio-api

I have implemented a `AuthorizationHandler` according to [an official Twilio tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/tutorials/how-to-secure-your-csharp-aspnet-core-app-by-validating-incoming-twilio-requests?code-sample=code-use-filter-attribute-to-validate-twilio-requests&code-language=cs&code-sdk-version=default) but it only works for SMS-related requests but not voice-related requests (always fail the validation).

Below is the one and only `AuthorizationHandler` applied to different controllers that accept POST request from Twilio to notify my API of inbound and outbound voice calls, inbound SMS, and status change to outbound SMS:

```
public class TwilioInboundRequestAuthorizationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<TwilioInboundRequestRequirement>
{
    private readonly RequestValidator _requestValidator;

    public TwilioInboundRequestAuthorizationHandler(IOptionsSnapshot<AppOptions> options)
    {
        // Initialize the validator
        _requestValidator = new RequestValidator(options.Value.TwilioAuthToken);
    }

    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, TwilioInboundRequestRequirement requirement)
    {
        if (context.Resource is AuthorizationFilterContext mvcContext)
        {
            // Examine MVC-specific things like routing data.
            HttpRequest httpRequest = mvcContext.HttpContext.Request;

            if (IsValidRequest(httpRequest))
            {
                context.Succeed(requirement);
            }
            else
            {
                /* Omitted some code that logs the error to a cloud service */
                context.Fail();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        // Check if the requirement is fulfilled.
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private bool IsValidRequest(HttpRequest request) {
        // The Twilio request URL
        var requestUrl = RequestRawUrl(request);
        var parameters = ToDictionary(request.Form);
        // The X-Twilio-Signature header attached to the request
        var signature = request.Headers["X-Twilio-Signature"];
        return _requestValidator.Validate(requestUrl, parameters, signature);
    }

    private static string RequestRawUrl(HttpRequest request)
    {
        return $"{request.Scheme}://{request.Host}{request.Path}{request.QueryString}";
    }

    private static IDictionary<string, string> ToDictionary(IFormCollection collection)
    {
        return collection.Keys
            .Select(key => new { Key = key, Value = collection[key] })
            .ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value.ToString());
    }
}

public class TwilioInboundRequestRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
}
```

**EDIT:**

According to a suggestion from Twilio Support, I should change the `RequestRawUrl` to strip away the port number from the URL. However, that causes the validation working for voice calls only, while for SMS it doesn't work anymore (opposite to the original issue). I suspect Twilio has been setting an incorrect signature in the request header for either voice or SMS.

I changed the `RequestRawUrl` function from

```
private static string RequestRawUrl(HttpRequest request)
{
    return $"{request.Scheme}://{request.Host}{request.Path}{request.QueryString}";
}
```

to

```
private static string RequestRawUrl(HttpRequest request)
{
    return $"{request.Scheme}://{request.Host.Host}{request.Path}{request.QueryString}";
}
```

Comment: Is there any other difference between the URLs you are using for voice and SMS webhooks?

Comment: @philnash nope - other than them being in different controllers

Comment: If it works for SMS then it should work for voice too, there's nothing different in the algorithm. I'd be looking for any other differences between how it's implemented, whether there's some middleware on one controller and not another, are all the parameters making it through to the voice controller?

Comment: @philnash see edit

Comment: Do you have the URL set differently in the Twilio console for SMS and calls?

Comment: @philnash one is https://kelvin.com:12345/api/voice and the other is https://kelvin.com:12345/api/InboundMessages

Comment: I can see that you're still having this conversation with Twilio support too. I think that is probably the best place to continue this as they are best placed to help and this is not likely a code issue.

Answer (score 3):

We had a similar problem. What it boiled down to was that for some methods, (like SMS) the request URL comes in as https, and other methods (like TwiML voice script callbacks) the request comes in written as http.

If the request comes in written as http, the .Validate(...) method will fail on you, even though it is a valid request.

So to get the Twilio request validator to work, we simply rewrite the request URL.

```
    private bool IsValidRequest(HttpRequestBase request)
    {
        var signature = request.Headers["X-Twilio-Signature"];
        Debug.WriteLine(request.Headers["X-Twilio-Signature"]);
        var requestUrl = rewriteUri(request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
        Debug.WriteLine("URI is: " + rewriteUri(request.Url.AbsoluteUri));

        return _requestValidator.Validate(requestUrl, request.Form, signature);
    }

    private string rewriteUri(string absoluteUri)
    {
        //check to make sure we're not replacing 'https' with 'httpss'
        if (!absoluteUri.Contains("https"))
        {
            return Regex.Replace(absoluteUri, @"http", "https");
        }
        return absoluteUri;
    }
```

Comment: You are a lifesaver.  This fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Thanks for this! My webhook was "https" but the incoming request was only "http".

Comment: Might be worth reporting a bug to Twilio for this. These requests really shouldn't come in http.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same issue when running locally behind ngrok, but not when deployed. I figured out that the RequestValidator expects the original ngrok URL, but by default we are passing localhost. I ended up solving it like so:

```
    private bool IsValidRequest(HttpRequest request)
    {
        var requestUrl = RequestRawUrl(request);
        var parameters = ToDictionary(request.Form);
        var signature = request.Headers["X-Twilio-Signature"];

        // Check if we are running locally and need to pass ngrok through for validation to succeed.
        if (request.Headers.ContainsKey("X-Original-Host") && request.Headers["X-Original-Host"][0].Contains("ngrok"))
        {
            requestUrl = requestUrl.Replace(request.Headers["Host"][0], request.Headers["X-Original-Host"][0]);
        }

        return _requestValidator.Validate(requestUrl, parameters, signature);
    }
```

Comment: If you're using ngrok locally just use the http url rather than the https version

Answer (score -1):

If you using ngrok, verifier expects ngrok URL (i think same thing with other proxies)
In PHP the original host can be get from HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_HOST, maybe this would help you somehow