# Unable to validate Twilio incoming SMS webhook with AWS lambda

Tags: validation, aws-lambda, twilio, webhooks

I'm trying to integrate my app with Twilio for SMS service.
I would like to get notified each time there is an incoming SMS message.

Here is what I did

1- I define a lambda and ApiGateway with proxy integration

2- I added the endpoint url to the webhook settings in Twilio console

Once I send an SMS to the Twilio number the lambda is indeed triggered and I'm able to process the message.

**However**, When I try to use the Twilio validator in order to validate the even I keep getting that the event is invalid

Here is the code snippet handling the validation for post reqeust

```py
validator = RequestValidator(<'auth token'>)
post_body_dict  = {key: value[0] for key, value in parse_qs(body).items()}
url = <'url as defined in Twilio's console'>
sig = event['headers'].get("X-Twilio-Signature")
is_valid = validator.validate(url, params, sig)
```

Notes

1 - The body of the request arrives as a string of query params even though it's a POST request (param1=val1&param2=val2...)

2 - I also tried removing '+' when processing the body string (except the + prefix from the phone numbers)

3 - I also tried get request but then the query params don't arrive as a string of params but a parsed dict.

4 - I only managed to validate the request if I didn't used lambda, then the request had the original query params string from the sender concatenated to the url but I did not manage to replicate this is a lambda environment .

I went over Twilio's documents but it seems to me that when I use GET request I lose the original order of the query params in the lambda even arriving from the api gateway. And regarding post, I have no idea why I'm unable to make it work.

Resources I tried:
[Cannot Validate Twilio Request in an AWS Lambda Custom Authorizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47361642/cannot-validate-twilio-request-in-an-aws-lambda-custom-authorizer),
[Twilio Request Validation always fail for Voice Call (but works for SMS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49868419/twilio-request-validation-always-fail-for-voice-call-but-works-for-sms),
[twilio webhook: fail to validate signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71853352/twilio-webhook-fail-to-validate-signature),
https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/guides/webhook-request,
[twilio RequestValidator not working in python wsgi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76625736/twilio-requestvalidator-not-working-in-python-wsgi)

and some others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of Twilio support I was able to solve the issue (only for POST requests so this is was I will use).
The issue was that when getting the url encoded post body, I converted it to a dictionary but without the empty values.

```
parsed_dict = parse_qs(event["body"])
result_dict = {key: value[0] for key, value in parsed_dict.items()}
```

What I should have done was

```
parsed_dict = parse_qs(event["body"], keep_blank_values=True)
result_dict = {key: value[0] for key, value in parsed_dict.items()}
```

then validator(url=url, params=result_dict , signiture=sig) worked

Regarding GET, I'm still not sure how to make it work with api gateway lambda